# signed integer is greater than maximum during zip file read boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, zip, boto3, databricks

Below is the requirement:
Unzip files present in S3 folder to another S3 folder using AWS Databricks.

I have used the below code to unzip the files in the S3,for small files it works fine, although for zip files with the size of > 1.5 GB it doesn't working and throws below error.

**OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum**

Below is the code snipped iam using

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = "bucket"
unzip_folder = 'unzipfolder/'

for key_file in zip_paths:  
  zip_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucket, 
                             key=key_file)
  buffer = io.BytesIO(zip_obj.get()["Body"].read())
  z = zipfile.ZipFile(buffer)
  for filename in z.namelist():
      file_info = z.getinfo(filename)
      s3_resource.meta.client.upload_fileobj(
          z.open(filename),
          Bucket=bucket,
          Key= unzip_folder + f'{filename}'
          )
```

[image: Error Log 1]

[image: Error Log 2]

Comment: It'd be helpful if you included the complete error message with traceback and all. With the limited information included, it seems you may be running into a bug/limitation with ssl, https://bugs.python.org/issue42853, but it's not really possible to say at this point.